# why arima uses differencing transform not the log transform to make data stationary?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, heteroscedasticity, logarithm

I am currently working on time series project and i am naive.

I would like to ask, there exist strict stationary, differencing stationarity.

If i understood correct the first order differencing removes varying mean but not varying variance?
So, how to remove varying variance?

To my knowledge varying variance is often removed using log transform.
But, in Box Jenkins ARIMA second order differencing is considered.

My question is: Does the transformation like log transformation and second order differencing will have same effect to remove variance and make data stationary?

Please correct me if my understanding is not correct

Comment: No. You could see it by comparing the two approaches on simulated data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dr. Hardy,